# switch statement for taxonomy content

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

I'm trying to check if a taxonomy in a post matches a string, however my code isn't working and it's always outputting the first item..

```
   $i=get_the_term_list($post->ID,'tax-athlete');

   switch (has_term( $i, 'athlete' )) {
        case "John Doe":
            echo "john";
            break;
        case "Mark Webber":
            echo "mark";
            break;
        case "Jane Smith":
            echo "jane";
            break;
        default:
            echo "author";
    }
```

My normal code to simply display the athlete works.

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list($post->ID,'athlete','Athlete: ',', ','');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is all upside down and scrambled. What you would want to do is to check for a specific term and then feed that into [`get_the_term_list()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list), not the other way around.  Also, evaluate your switch to true.

I would probably first get an array of terms attached to the post and then check if my desired term is in that array to make my statement a bit more efficient. For this, I will use [`wp_get_post_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) and only get the term names as it seems if this is what you are testing against

With this being said, you can try something like this; (*CAVEAT: Untested*)

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'TAXONOMY NAME', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
switch (true) {
    case in_array( 'John Doe', $terms ):
        $name = 'john';
        break;
    case in_array( 'Mark Webber', $terms ):
        $name = 'mark';
        break;
    case in_array( 'Jane Smith', $terms ):
        $name = 'jane';
        break;
    default:
        $name = 'author';
}

echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'TAXONOMY NAME', $name, ', ' );
```